# How to plot and only have few selected states in stead of all 50 of them

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have figured out how to plot the big picture. But I failed so many attempts trying to come up with a bar chart that has only a few selected states.

My code is:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(15,20))
plt.barh(final['states'], final['act_17_composite'])

plt.title('ACT 2017 composite rate by States')
```

[image]

Comment: Which states do you want to include?

Comment: I 'll say let's use PA, VA, and CA as an example.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it answered your question - that way the question is marked as such for future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the underlying dataframe I am speculating, but for a small number of states it might suffice to do something like

```py
final2 = df.loc[(final['states'] == 'PA') | 
                (final['states'] == 'VA') | 
                (final['states'] == 'CA')]
plt.barh(final2['states'], final2['act_17_composite'])
```

For longer sets of states it would be better to do

```py
s = ['PA', 'VA', 'CA']
final2 = final.iloc[final.index[final['states'] == e].tolist()[0] for e in s]
plt.barh(final2['states'], final2['act_17_composite'])
```